# Custom teaser text in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a custom field named "field_blurb." Is it possible to make this the text shown in a teaser instead of the default which is from the body field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly, just go to the content types display settings, and pick the teaser build mode.
Drag the body to hidden, and set the blurb to be displayed. Done.